# Platform specific newline character in annotation

Tags: java, annotations, newline

I'd like to use platform specific newline character in `String` provided in annotation element.

What should I use below instead of `???`?

```
@Scenario(title = "This text should match multiline text from file stored on disk " + ???
        + "saved with platform specific newline character")
```

When I replace `???` with `System.lineSeparator()` I get compilation error `Attribute value must be constant`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use non-constant values as properties of annotations. The string that you hand to the annotation must be a [*compile-time constant* as specified in JLS §15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html).

Within the class file, the annotation properties are directly stored together as meta-data with the annotation's declaration. By concept, attributes can therefore not be resolved at runtime as it would be necessary for resolving a runtime-dependant property.

As an alternative, you should rather post-process an annotation's property, e.g. by simply replacing the string's line break characters by the runtime's `System.getProperty("line.separator")` value.

Comment: Post-processing was the easiest solution in my case, as I own this annotation. Thank you and Erwin for the hints!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Annotation parameter values have to be compile-time constants. The error that you got says the same.

And a platform-dependant value is, by definition, not a compile-time constant, as it should be different depending on the platform on which you run it. So it cannot be part of an annotation parameter value.

You could do the translation where ever you output the value of the parameter, replacing every single `\n` with `System.lineSeparator()`.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is introduce a constant expression:

```
private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
```

And use it in the annotation:

```
@Scenario(title = "This text should match multiline text from file stored on disk "
                + LINE_SEPARATOR
                + "saved with platform specific newline character")
```

However `LINE_SEPARATOR` needs to be a constant itself and can't be initialised with `System.lineSeparator()`. At least it makes it easier to change the line separator in all your annotations at once...

---

Alternatively you could change your annotation to accept an array of lines:

```
public @interface Scenario {
  String[] titleLines();
}
```

And annotate with:

```
@Scenario(titleLines = {"This text should match multiline text from file stored on disk ",
                        "saved with platform specific newline character" })
```

Then you can insert a line separator as required in the code that consumes the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Java only knows the format string to do just that: `String.format("%n")`. So if the annotation somehow is passed to a formatter, that might be tried. Slim chance.

Otherwise **"\r\n"** for Windows might function everywhere.